# Finding out if an IPv6 prefix falls within a certain range?

Tags: ipv6, utilities

Does anyone know of a tool or utility that can be used to quickly find out if an IPv6 prefix falls within a certain range?

For instance given the input prefix range of `fe80-febf` and the input prefix of `fe79` it would return true to indicate that the latter argument is within the former.

Or another example might be given the input prefix range of `fe80-febf` and the input prefix of `fe81` it would return false to indicate that the latter argument would be outside the range specified in the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd break out the python, personally.

```
>>> x = 'fe79'
>>> int('fe80', 16) <= int(x, 16) <= int('febf', 16)
False
>>> x = 'fe81'
>>> int('fe80', 16) <= int(x, 16) <= int('febf', 16)
True
```

Comment: Hmm if there was a way to do this in Javascript I think it would be easiest since most people have that lying around...I'll bet there's a way to do that...looking further into this...

Comment: I suppose I could just throw it into codepad.org too...

Comment: Okay here's a url to the codepad.org of your suggestion: http://bit.ly/uXU53j

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Fully expanding the address to the 39 character string representation and then using string comparison?

Not the fastest but maybe the easiest